# why do you not pronounce the 'z' in riz au lait?

Tags: prononciation

Riz au lait is pronounced like riole, why not rizole?

Comment: For the very same reason we do not pronounce the 'z' in *nez au vent*.

Comment: Why not nezovent?

Comment: Similar question: [Liaison before “à”](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22632)

Answer (score 8):

Les liaisons sont interdites après un nom au singulier suivi d'un adjectif.

Voici une référence pour les liaisons obligatoires, falcultatives et interdites sur le site de l'[Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#46_strong-em-liaisons-em-strong).

On peut trouver des informations également intéressantes [ici](http://www.projet-pfc.net/le-francais-explique/la-liaison/types-de-liaisons.html).

Comme indiqué par @GAMPUB en commentaire voici une [liste d'exceptions](http://research.jyu.fi/phonfr/93.html).

Comment: There are some exceptions with special collocations: accent_aigu, pot_au feu, nuit_et jour, mot_à mot, etc. There is a non exhaustive list [here](http://research.jyu.fi/phonfr/93.html).

Comment: @GAMPUB: Merci pour le lien, je l'ai introduit dans la réponse.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you picked this example in particular, there is almost no liaison with *the letter* 'z'. (not the sound)

We say "*nez à nez*" or "*si vous tenez à rester*" (both are possible for this one). There are a few counterexample (like "*chez eux*"), but in almost every case, there is no liaison with 'z'.

There are three types of liaisons : Obligatoire (compulsory), Interdite (forbidden) and Facultative. Then you have to learn which is which.

[This (ugly but useful) site](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-87708.php) could help you on that.

Comment: On fait la liaison dans « vous tenez à rester »

Comment: @Toto Pas moi. C'est une liaison facultative, comme souvent pour les verbes. On peut lier dans "je vais écrire" mais en pratique on l'entend rarement.

Comment: @Toto j'ai trouvé un meilleur exemple : "vous prenez un menu ?", on ne fait pas la liaison (pas moi ni laplupart des serveurs en tout cas)

Comment: Désolé, mais personnellement, je fais cette liaison.

Comment: C'est le principe de la liaison facultative j'imagine ^^ J'ai édité ma réponse en conséquence.

Comment: You might want to clarify you mean "almost no liaison with the letter 'z'". The sound /z/ is  the most common sound used in liaisons (but usually after a word written with the letter 's').

Comment: @sumelic Can you give examples ? I meant the letter, not the sound.

Comment: Examples with the sound /z/? I was just referring to common cases where it indicates plurality such as elles-z-aiment, les-z-arbres, les grands-z-états.

Comment: For nouns ending in the letter -z, facultative liaison is possible with the plurals as with every other noun: les riz_italiens, les nez_épatés, etc.